# Java Spring Boot - AWS objects keep getting recreated/reappearing even after being deleted - been getting charged for almost a year now with AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I signed up for Free Tier account with AWS so that I could provide a Java Spring Boot application.  It is a very small and simple program with a very small MySQL of about 10000 rows of simple data.

I keep getting incurred charges every month and contacting customer support, then following their instructions to delete load balancers, instances etc. but then a few months later I will get charged again and again these same objects keep getting recreated.

How do I just delete everything so that I won't be charged ever again?  I am not even using this application anymore and don't need it.  Here is a screenshot of my EC2 dashboard and also the billing breakdown.  I've deleted all of these objects before and they keep reappearing.

[image]

I have literally had it up to here with AWS!!!

Comment: I haven't used JSB, but chances are that it is re-creating the resources it needs.  So as long as it is there, it will create other things when you trigger it.  AWS itself does not randomly add resources.

Comment: Are there different resources created for JSB applications?  I used EC2 and some elastic beanstalk object when I set it up initially.  There must be some root object that is recreating all this....

Comment: Sorry, I don't use JSB, but yes you must have missed deleting some root object.  Hopefully a JSB user will see this.

Comment: Is there any chance that you used elastic beanstalk to create the application?  It may be recreating this stuff for you, that's one of its functions, to manage the application environment.

Comment: I followed a random tutorial on youtube.  I think that might be what I did.  Do you know how to undo this?  I've talked to their customer support almost 4 times and they have'nt been able to fix this.

Comment: "I followed a random tutorial on youtube. " - it might help to watch it again and remind yourself about what steps you went through.  If that doesn't work you could write out the steps and edit your question to include them.

Comment: Yes, I backtraced it and there was an elastic beanstalk and S3 bucket that was created.  So if I delete these two objects (for the beanstalk it would be the environments I created), will this stop the instances from being recreated again?

Comment: That seems likely, but we're guessing without seeing a list of everything created and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that you have two auto-scaling groups. One of the features with auto-scaling groups is to make sure a certain number of EC2 instances are running. That means that even if you terminate an instance manually, the auto-scaling group will do its job and launch a replacement instance.

Deleting the auto-scaling groups first will likely help here. I would also not be surprised if there is one or more CloudFormation stacks in your account, so would make sure to look there to delete those as well.

Comment: What is a cloud formation stack?  I just backtraced what I did originally and I had created an elastic beanstalk and and S3 bucket to deploy the Spring Boot jar.  Somehow the customer support missed these objects and now I am going to try to delete those.  do you think this is the reason why the instances kept reappearing?

Comment: CloudFormation is an AWS service used to create AWS resources through code. A CloudFormation stack represents a set of resources created and managed by CloudFormation. 

Sounds like when you created your Elastic Beanstalk application, it created a number of resources in your account. Start by deleting the items in Elastic Beanstalk and the delete the ASG if they still exist after that.